# Using Array with Mongodb & EJS

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I'm trying to find the very simplest way to use arrays within MongoDB and EJS.

In this very simple example on the front end a user can click a button and add a value to an array.

```
$("#buttonOne").click(function() {
food.push("Kiwi");
$("#foodObject").val(food)
});

$("#buttonTwo").click(function() {
food.push("Taco");
$("#foodObject").val(food)
});
```

Then on the front end see it within an input:

```
<input id='foodObject' type="text" name="foodObject" placeholder="foodObject">
```

The idea is then to pass the array to mongo

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    foodObject: [ ],
});
```

And then be able to use the array with EJS:

```
<h3 class='text-center'> <%= currentUser.foodObject[0] %>  </h3>
```

So if a user had added both Kiwi and Taco to the array I'd want foodObject[0] to return just Kiwi.

Is this possible?

Currently it returns the full string. i.e "Kiwi, Taco"

Comment: What do you mean when you say it returns the full string? Does `<%= currentUser.foodObject[0] %>` return all the array elements?

Comment: Right. Currently it looks like it saves the array as a string. So it prints "Kiwi, Taco" For foodObject[0] not only Kiwi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you send `foodObject` to server as string and not as array. So the array you return with ejs has only one element. In the server you have to split the string to array and then save it like this.
Server side code:

```
String formValue = req.body.foodObject;
var foodObjects = formValue.split(',');
```

Then you save `foodObjects` array to mongoose schema.

Comment: Awesome! This worked perfectly! Thank you for the help! I went with  foodObject: req.body.foodObject.split(','),

Comment: Glad to help you! ;)